# Is there a jQuery event equivilant to when a new item is added to the FireBug console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to check the CSS of an element every time a new entry is added to the FireBug console with jQuery.

I have the CSS checking working fine, but not the event for triggering the check.

I think I'm looking for something like "ajaxComplete" or "ajaxStart", but neither of those are getting triggered.

Example:

```
$(document).live("ajaxComplete", function() {

   if($('#foo').css('display') == 'none') {

      alert("no!");

   } else {

      alert("yes!");

   }

});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you not wrap `console.log()` in your own function and add your tracking code to that?

Comment: Err, I'm not sure if you understood what I'm trying to achieve.. Everytime an AJAX GET request is sent, I want to check the CSS of an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment

> Everytime an AJAX GET request is sent, I want to check the CSS of an element.

It looks like you want the global [ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) event.  The second parameter to the handler is the xhr object, which will give you a `responseText` property containing the result of the ajax load.

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr) {
  alert("I just got back " + xhr.responseText);
});
```

Comment: After trying your example the callback function wasn't being fired still.. Any ideas ?

Comment: @Sean - check the console for errors, and also check the network console to make sure the request is going over and coming back successfully

Comment: Good idea. I'm getting this error "No relay set (used as window.postMessage targetOrigin), cannot send cross-domain message". Also yes the requests are sent and completed correctly in the console.

Comment: Ahh - sounds like you're trying to send a cross-domain ajax request - that'll throw an error every time unless you have CORS set up.  You'll need to structure things so that your ajax request is sent on the same domain that your page is on.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that this is running in a Greasemonkey script and it's not my website so I can't modify the AJAX requests. But the request seems to be going through fine as far as I can see. The error only shows when the GM script is running, and even then the request still seems to go through fine.

Comment: @Sean - it sounds like there's *some* problem in your Greasemonkey script.  I don't know mush about this, so I would recommend asking a new question.  Once you get this working, you should be able to use the method I posted above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8420/discussion-between-sean-chapman-and-adam-rackis)